# width device-width What is what? Confused

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, mobile-website

I've read two articles:
https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html
https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

I am really confused why is `width` size of window in first article and size of screen in second article.
What have I missed?

Comment: The word `width` appears on the first page 78 times, and 62 times on the second. Could you be a little more specific as to what you are actually referring to here …?

Comment: @CBroe That's why he's confused

Comment: Stack Overflow didn't let me post another links..
[mobile](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/pix/viewport/mobile_mediaqueries.jpg)

Comment: @CBroe
[desktop](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/pix/viewport/desktop_mediaqueries.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see below image 
[image]

Device Screen or Device Width is the width of entire desktop or monitor. In my case it is 1679px wide.  (marked with yellow highlighter.. I have highlighted Screen height instead of width. Sorry for that.

And width Screen size window with id width of browser window . in my case this is 1100px wide approximate . i have marked this with red pen.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am confused about those two pictures:
[mobile](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/pix/viewport/mobile_mediaqueries.jpg)
[desktop](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/pix/viewport/desktop_mediaqueries.jpg)

Comment: In mobile, some times content goes outside device width. in that case, content is not visible without scroll. and mobile browser width increase and become greater than device width. In any case, browser width is called as Window width. and Device or Screen actual width is called as Device width. For Desktop you can see firefox opened .. width of firefox window will taken as Window width, and desktop width will be taken as device width..

Comment: Click. Now, I finally understand. I absolutely missed this point. Thanks

Comment: When you want to do work for a specific screen width, then you you device-width media query for example '@media(device-width:320px)'  and you want to do work related to browser width, you will use @media(width:320px) .